# Messagebus is using more than 4 GB RAM

Tags: memory, memory-usage, htop

I have just checked my Server and it is running relativly low on RAM. There are currently no users on anyone of the Services Installed (Jitsi, Rocket.Chat, OnlyOffice Workspace) as they're all still in configuration, but I got 15.6 GB Ram Usage where a significant Part comes from Messagebus.

Is this normal?
Is there a way to reduce Ram Usage?

Here is a Picture from htop:

[Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnVYl.jpg)

EDIT after Shift + H:

[Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEIiV.png)

Comment: Press shift-H and look again.

Comment: Addet It to the Post - but Shill over 15GB RAM Usage where messagebus is over 22%... This seems so much! O.o

Comment: Looks like elasticsearch is the running process, and that doesn't seem much at all!

Comment: But It's Idle so nobody is searching. Tehre are not even other users with login credentials than me. Is 15GB not to much for this senario? EDIT: I just researched a little and it turns out elastisearch is used for Full-Text Search. A Premium Feature that is not even activated (Cause I run the community Edition) on my Server.